# register user then upload image with rxjava 1 & retrofit2

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2

I'm new to RxJava, I'm having two REST API for:

1. register user.
2. upload his image.

**Registration API**

```
@POST("services/v1/users/register")
Observable<User> registerUser(@Body User user);
```

**Upload image API**

```
@Multipart
@POST("services/v1/users/{id}/profile-image-upload")
Observable<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(@Path("id") int userId,
    @Part("description") RequestBody description, @Part MultipartBody.Part photo);
```

I have tested them separately & working fine, my issue that I want during registration to first register the user so the returned object is having the user id after creation in remote server than use it in second call for the upload & after success both requests I need to return the User object to caller function only ignoring the image upload API return.

Appreciate providing sample code for this.

Comment: `retrofitService.uploadPhoto(user).flatMap(user -> retrofitService.uploadPhoto(user.getId(), getDescription(), getPhoto()).subscribe(this::doSmthWithUser);`

Comment: @Than Sorry it is not clear where u call registerUser & I think you are calling uploadPhoto twice?

Comment: Yeah, first time should be register

Comment: This is not working as subscribe is expecting type of ResponseBody not user object. Let me write the calls as suggested, and it already gave error "Incompatible types" in android studio. I'm not using lambda expression in example: `retrofitService.registerUser(user).flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<ResponseBody>>() {
 @Override
 public Observable<ResponseBody> call(User user) {
  return retrofitService.uploadUserPhoto(user.getId(), getDescription(), getPhoto());
 }
})).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `flatMap` here as already suggested in the comments. Here's how:

```
api.registerUser(new User())
            .flatMap(new Function<User, ObservableSource<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<ResponseBody> apply(@NonNull User user) throws Exception {
                    return api.uploadPhoto(user.id, description, photo);
                }
            })
            // schedulers and subscription here
```

*The code assumes you have an object `api` that was built by retrofit to implement the given api requests*

I don't really know where `description` and `photo` come from, but you probably do. I also `flatMap` it to a `ResponseBody`, but you can return whatever you need.

Here's how you can do it in Java 8:

```
api.registerUser(new User())
            .flatMap(user ->  api.uploadPhoto(user.id, description, photo))
            // Subscribers and schedulers
```

The key is the `flatMap`, which lets the first call finish and then uses the result of that call to create another observable. In this case, you just call the upload photo method.

**Edit**

After the comment I now can give you this approach (There's probably several ways to do this):

```
api.registerUser(new User())
            .flatMap(new Function<User, ObservableSource<User>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<User> apply(@NonNull final User user) throws Exception {
                    return api.uploadPhoto(user.id, description, photo)
                            .map(new Function<ResponseBody, User>() {
                                @Override
                                public User apply(@NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) throws Exception {
                                    return user;
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            // schedulers and subscription here
```

Java 8:

```
api.registerUser(new User())
            .flatMap(user -> api.uploadPhoto(user.id, description, photo)
                    .map(responseBody -> user));
```

So basically I'm just mapping the result of the image upload to another object which is the created user by the previous call. This will let the calling code get the registered user object instead of the response body.

The cool thing about plugging this into the stream is that you let the upload finish and only then you map it to a user. So at the end you are sure that both the registration and the upload succeeded.

**2nd EDIT**

Just for the sake of completeness here's the RxJava 1 version. There's barely any difference:

```
api.registerUser(new User())
            .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<User> call(User user) {
                    return api.uploadPhoto(user.id, description, photo)
                            .map(new Func1<ResponseBody, User>() {
                                @Override
                                public User call(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                                    return user;
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            // schedulers and subscriptions
```

I'll leave the Java 8 version out since it seems from the comments that you're not using it. However, if you do need it it's quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I know this will work to upload image after getting user details. My issue referring back to my question "after success both requests I need to return the User object to caller function only ignoring the image upload API return.". The above suggestion will return Observable<ResponseBody> while I need to return ObservableSource<User>.

Comment: But that's very easy to do. Let me update the answer

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using rxjava 1 I didn't find ObservableSource class & Interface Function doesn't have apply method. I know it should be easy to do but still starter in rxjava.

Comment: @AshrafFouad there you go

Comment: Many many many thanks for the solution and your patience :) appreciate if you have reference to website or article for operators for beginners to share.